# How should i remove my textboxes that are dynamically added

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my Jquery code

```
  var currentItem=1;
      $('.industry_button').click(function(){
          currentItem=currentItem+1;
          var strToAdd = "<div class='row' style='margin-top:8px; display:none;'><div class='delrow_industry'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span></div><div class='col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2' style='margin-left: 17.5%;'><input type='text' name='domain[]" +currentItem+ "' placeholder='Industry/Domain' class='industry_text form-control'></div><label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='domainExclude" +currentItem+ "' value='1'>Exclude</label></div><br>";
          $('#industry').append(strToAdd);  
      })
```

code for removing textboxes:

```
$('.delrow_industry').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove('rd');
    })
```

Comment: where is `#industry`

Comment: You code works, but the `<div>` has css `display:none`. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/fshL4zj7/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
    var newjobindustry=0;
$(".industryBtn").click(function(){
    newjobindustry=newjobindustry+1;
    $("#addjobIndustry").append("<div class='row rd'><div class='col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-md-offset-1'><div class='delrow'><span class='pull-left'><img src='/img/minus.png'></span></div></div><div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1'><input type='text' name='domain[]' value='' placeholder='Industry/Domain' class='industry_text jobTextInput autocomplete col-md-12' id='industry'></div><label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='domainExclude_"+newjobindustry+"' id='domainExclude_"+newjobindustry+"' class='domainExclude' value='1'/> Exclude</label></div>");
        $(":checkbox").labelauty();
        $(".labelauty-unchecked,.labelauty-checked").css("display","none");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
var strToAdd = "<div class='row' style='margin-top:8px; display:none;'>
```

You have a `display:none` which makes your div unvisible while adding.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tjkpzovb/3/)

Remove your Two `<br>` and `style='margin-left: 17.5%;'` to work properly.

[DEMO Modified](http://jsfiddle.net/tjkpzovb/6/)

Comment: Thank u. Code working but how can i reduce the space between two field

Comment: @M.Athishkrishna now see the new DEMO Modified.

Comment: Why u r using trigger and console

Comment: no i have added jquery mobile with that if you are not using jquery mobile no sweat just leave that part of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74321/discussion-between-m-athish-krishna-and-kawinesh-sk).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74395/discussion-between-m-athish-krishna-and-kawinesh-sk).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("click",".delrow_industry", function(){
    if( currentItem > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('#delin').remove();
            currentItem--; 
    }

    })
```